# Hibernate: UPDATE with a user-provided SQL code

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria

I've been reading the documentation, but I couldn't find any information about it.

Is it possible to have Hibernate send user-provided SQL queries in order to UPDATE or to INSERT an object in the database?

In other words, is it possible to have `session.saveOrUpdate( myObject );` , which generates `update mySchema.myObject set field1=?, field2=?, field3=? where unique_key=?`
to be replaced with a manual query from a user-provided String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well described in the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct). There are caveats, though : the session and the second-level cache aren't aware of the changes made to the entities, the version field is not updated, etc.

And if HQL is still not sufficient, you may always fall back to [SQL queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querysql).